# Ajax FormData file upload not working [JQuery] [PHP]

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, upload

My upload form isn't working for some reason, when I submit the form the PHP file runs and my $_FILES variable is empty.  I've been stuck for hours and I feel like I've been through every post on this site and I just don't understand what's going wrong.

HTML

```
    <form id="uploadform" name="uploadform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input id="realupload" name="realupload" type="file" multiple/>
      <input id="uploadsubmit" type="submit" value="upload"/>
</form>
```

JQuery

```
$('#uploadsubmit').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "upload.php",
            data: function(){
                alert("test");
                var data = new FormData();
                data.append("realupload", jQuery("#realupload").get(0).files[0]);
                return data;
            }
            ,
            processData:false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function(theData){
                $('#innercontent').html(theData);
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#innercontent').html("ERROR, HELP");
            }
        });

    } 
});
```

PHP (upload.php)

```
<?php
//upload.php
if (isset($_FILES["realupload"]))
{
    echo "SUCCESSFUL UPLOAD " . $_FILES["realupload"]["error"];
}
else{
    echo "FILES NOT SET";
}
?>
```

- The PHP file is just a test file to check if the upload worked
- FILES NOT SET is output every time
- The alert inside of the ajax data function doesn't run, I'm not sure if it's should be
- Trying to create a multiple file uploader

Could this be to do with the server? There is already a forum uploaded on there that in itself allows uploads, so I don't think that that is the case, but I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Edit: Guys, thanks for the links, but you can now upload files with HTML5 and the XmlHttpRequest2 object and I'm trying to figure that out.

Comment: As many have mentioned you cannot use AJAX to upload files, but there are some tricks to learn. Have a look at this tutorial that shows how to use an iframe to post file uploads - http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1766159

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Answer (score -2):

Just use new jquery library `jquery-2.1.1.min.js` from http://jquery.com/download/

It will definitely solve your problem. A few days before i was stuck with same problem so I gave try for above library it did work for me.

Answer (score -3):

you cant send files by ajax, you will have to use PHP directly to do that.